# Аналог команды bash source для python

Tags: python, bash

В общем есть код на баше, надо переписать его на питон.
На баше с помощью команды source подгружаются переменные, которые я потом использую. Как бы это реализовать на Python, чтобы не пришлось переписывать уже готовые файлы с переменными для баша?
Пример файла из которого подгружаются переменные:

```
VERSION=1.0
COMMENT_OK="asd"
COMMENT_FAIL="asd"
COMMAND="grep asd"
EXPIRE=123
```

Comment: Приведите пример содержания файла из которого подгружаются переменные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно подойдет [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html)

Answer (score 2):

execfile не подойдет?

```
execfile('path/file.ext')
print COMMAND, VERSION
```

Comment: Блин, точно!
Черт, а я уже почти изобрел такой велосипед... :)

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что это быдлокод- подскажите как лучше.

```
import shutil
shutil.copyfile('path/filename.ext', 'filename.py') # path/filename.ext это путь к файлу
from filename import *
print VERSION, COMMAND
```

Comment: Ну, можно развить как-то так:

# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
f=open('values.txt', 'r') # path/filename.ext это путь к файлу
f2=open('filename.py', 'w')
f2.write(f.read())
f2.close()
f.close()

import filename

value_list = dir(filename)
while value_list:
  value = value_list.pop()
  if not value.startswith('__'):
    print value,'=', filename.__dict__[value]

Comment: @Ekkertan я упростить просил, а не убыдлокодить :) мне не нравится необходимость копирования файла перед импортом. Хотелось бы нечто вроде

    __import__('path/filename.ext')
Но можно импортировать похоже только питоновые расширения py и pyd.